# GET data from MongoDB and display on the front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, handlebars.js

I´ve just started learning NodeJS to use as a back-end of my applications, but this is my first time working with a server-side technology.

I am trying to build a simple app which is a form where I want to insert the data into the database (mongodb) and get the data to display on the front end. I am using express-handlebars.

The data is successfully being saved into the database, however when I am trying to get the data from the database to display on the front end nothing happens.

Does anyone knows what may be wrong with my code ?

Thank you!!

//code begins here

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var assert = require('assert');

var url = 'mongodb://felipe:teste@ds033125.mlab.com:33125/form';
mongoose.connect(url);


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

// INSERT DATA INTO DATABASE(MONGODB)

```js
router.post('/insert', function(req, res, next) {
    
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    
    var itemSchema = new Schema({
        nome: String,
        sobrenome: String,
        nacionalidade: String,
        email: String
    });
    
    var CreateItem = mongoose.model('CreateItem', itemSchema);
    
    var item = new CreateItem({
        
        nome: req.body.getNome,
        sobrenome: req.body.getSobrenome,
        nacionalidade: req.body.getNacionalidade,
        email: req.body.getEmail
    });
    
    item.save(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(item.nome + ' was saved!');
    });
    
    
    
    res.redirect('/');
    console.log(item.nome + ' ' + item.sobrenome + ' was saved!'); 
});
```

// GET DATA FROM MONGODB AND DISPLAY ON THE FRONT END

```js
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});


router.get('/get-data', function(req, res, next) {
    
    var resultArray = [];
    
    mongoose.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        var cursor = db.collection('createitems').find();
        cursor.forEach(function(err, doc) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            resultArray.push(doc); 
        }, function() {
            db.close;
            res.render('index', {items: resultArray});
        });
    });
    
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

// HTML where the data will be displayed

```html
{{# each items}}
      <tr>                    
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <td class="data">{{ this.nome }}</td>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <td class="data">{{ this.sobrenome }}</td>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <td class="data">{{ this.nacionalidade }}</td>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <td class="data">{{ this.email }}</td>
         </div>
      </tr>
                    
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Can you try logging the `resultArray` before `res.render`? And for `handlebars`, you don't need `this.` just use `{{nome}}` `{{sobrenome}}` directly.

Comment: Hey Chau, thanks for your help! I´ve just tried to console.log(resultArray) before res.render, but nothing happens =/

I am going to keep trying haha

Answer (score 1):

do not use this: {{ this.nome }}
just use it like that: {{ nome }}

Answer (score -1):

Take reference from this example, i have created one route which you can access at (http://localhost:3000/test) you need to start the express server before accessing this route, This route will get the data from mongo db using mongoose and will return it. You can try this route using postman.

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    bodyparser = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose");

const router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyparser.json());

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('MongoDB connected successfully');
})

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    value: String
})

var data=mongoose.model("testdata", schema);

router.route('/test').get((req, res) => {
    data.find((err, (testdata);=> {
        if (err)
            console.log("Found some error" + err)
        else
            res.json(testdata);

    })
})


    app.use('/', router);



    app.listen(3000, function () {
        console.log('server started on port 3000');
    });
```